# pushing filtered values to a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering, shift

I'm working through an application to a coding bootcamp and am stuck. I could use some help seeing what I'm doing wrong. I'll post the question, the code and the output. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Question**:

Jim plans to buy new pack of assorted light bulbs.

He has heard that light bulbs are the most efficient when their serial number is an odd number and has exactly six digits.
He would appreciate you writing some code that figured out which serial numbers met the criteria.

When this function runs, it will receive an array of `serialNumbers` - something like

`[32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342]`

You need to add code that will ensure Jim collects the serial numbers he wants to keep in the provided variable, `efficientSerialNumbers`.

For the above array, this would mean that efficientSerialNumbers should end up containing

`[149143, 238791]`

We've added a log of serial numbers so you can see in the console what numbers are in the array when we try out your function. You are welcome to remove it, change it, do whatever you find useful!

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
    console.log(serialNumbers)
    const efficientSerialNumbers = [];
    // Write your code here

    for (let i= 0 ; i < serialNumbers.length ; i++)
    if (serialNumbers[i].length <=5 || serialNumbers[i].length >=7) {
    serialNumbers[i].shift()
    } else if (serialNumbers[i] % 2 === 1 && serialNumbers[i].length === 6 ) {
        serialNumbers[i].shift()
        efficientSerialNumbers.unshift(serialNumbers[i])
    }
        console.log(efficientSerialNumbers)
        console.log(serialNumbers)
    return efficientSerialNumbers;
}
```

**Output**

4 Passing
1 Failing

```
should return an array

    ✓  Well done!

logs

[ 123123 ]

[]

[ 123123 ]

 

should discard serial numbers with five or fewer figures

    ✓  Well done!

logs

[ 1, 123, 12345 ]

[]

[ 1, 123, 12345 ]

 

should discard serial numbers with seven or more figures

    ✓  Well done!

logs

[ 1234567, 123456789 ]

[]

[ 1234567, 123456789 ]

 

should discard even numbers

    ✓  Well done!

logs

[ 1234, 123456, 12345678 ]

[]

[ 1234, 123456, 12345678 ]

 

should keep all efficient numbers - those that are odd and have six digits in

  ✕ AssertionError: expected [] to deeply equal [ 234567, 456789 ]

logs

[ 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789 ]

[]

[ 123456, 234567, 345678, 456789 ]
```

Comment: How are you calling `findEfficientBulbs()`? I'm finding that the serial numbers' lengths are undefined because they are numbers, which don't have a length.

Comment: Your for-loop is missing `{...}`; where does it end?

Comment: What are you expecting `serialNumbers[i].shift()` to do? `serialNumbers[i]` is a number.

Comment: They provide an array of serialNumbers that only shows when you console.log()

Comment: For the purpose of the question i don't need to call thge function and serialNumbers is an array of provided serial numbers

Comment: I need to remove serial numbers that are even, have 5 or less and 7 or more numbers, then add the odd numbers with exactly 6 numbers to the second array, using a for loop and conditional logic

Comment: It's pretty hard to debug a function if you don't call it and the specifics of how you are calling it can make a difference. `shift()` is not a function you can call on a number.

Comment: I mean that on the website where I'm attempting this the function call is implied

Comment: How is it implied? Your function here doesn't run because you can call `shift()` on a number.

Comment: is there any way you can help me complete the last condition? I'm only doing what I was told to complete the prerequisite for the bootcamp

Comment: What are you attempting to do with the lines of code using `shift()`?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should properly open and close your `for` loop.
2. A number doesn't have `length` property, you could filter by number range and remainder.

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {

  const efficientSerialNumbers = [];

  for (let i= 0 ; i < serialNumbers.length ; i++) {
    const number = serialNumbers[i];
    if (number <= 999999 && number >= 100000 && number % 2 === 1) {
      efficientSerialNumbers.push(number);
    }
  }
  return efficientSerialNumbers;
}

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342]))
```

Btw in real life you don't need to push filtered values to a second array. An array already has `Array::filter()` method to make the job for you.

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
  return serialNumbers.filter(num => num <= 999999 && num >= 100000 && num % 2 === 1);
}

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342]))
```

If the serials are strings:

```js
function findEfficientBulbs(serialNumbers) {
  return serialNumbers.filter(num => num.length === 6 && num.at(-1) % 2 === 1);
}

console.log(findEfficientBulbs([32438, 34193, 149143, 4329429, 98537, 238791, 23492, 298342].map(n => n.toString())))
```

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle why convert a string to a string? i didn't provide a mixed number/string input solution

Comment: The way I'm using the .length property is for the length of the array which they provide behind the scenes

Comment: I understand there are better ways to achieve this, but they want me to use specific methods. I just don't get why what I have written will return an empty array for efficientSerialNumbers and how to correct it

Comment: @Room4Renzo serialNumbers[i].length doesn't make sense - you try to get length of a number which doesn't have any `.length` property

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev I was referring to the `num <= 999999 && num >= 100000`, seems easier to do `num.toString().length === 6`

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle, nope, that's waste of CPU, much slower on big lists of data. you cannot predict which amount of data your algorithm will be handling over time. scaling is a key so if you can do math it's much more efficient than working with strings. num.toString() - you should allocate memory for a string and do conversion, expensive

Comment: To be fair I wouldn't use JavaScript if working with big lists of data...

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle big is relative, could be small on a PC, could be big on a low budget smartphone

Comment: It's relatively negligible though. I ran some perf tests and yes `.toString()` is about 5-6 times slower, but still 2ms to process 1 million records vs 10.5ms seems negligible to me, even on a low budget smartphone.